# QGIS and percent values in slope map

Tags: qgis, raster, classification, slope

I create a slope map from a DEM downloaded with SRTM Downloader in QGIS 3.32.0-Lima. I searched in the internet trying to find the way to interpret the values of the left column in percent. For example:

- When I generate the slope map (Raster - Analysis - Slope) I select the following

[image: Creating the slope map]

- In my country I have 9 types to classify the slopes, so I left 9 classes.
- In the "Legend setup" I ticketed the "Use continuous legend" and in the "Format number" I left 2 decimals and I specified "The values are percents".

[image: Slope steps]

But I still have this crazy values

[image: Up than 100% in the red color]

How can I change the scale values to show from 0% to 100%?

Here you can see a view from the top to the bottom of the site

[image: Top view of the site]

And here another satellite view from South to North of the site.

[image: South to North view]

I need to add this values in the slope options

[image: Slope table]

Comment: Values are crazy because ratio 1:1 between the horizontal and vertical components does not make sense with that source data. The horizontal unit is degrees and the vertical unit is meters. A rough estimate of 111120 is often used gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html#description but a better option is to re-project the DEM into some projected coordinate system that is good for your area of interest.

Comment: Consider putting this (or a slightly expanded version) as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The slopes are "crazy" because your horizontal units are degrees and your vertical units are metres.

Consider reprojecting your DEM into a projected co-ordinate system relevant to your area of interest. That will give you horizontal units in metres.

Alternatively you can adjust your slopes using a conversion from degrees to metres. The issue with this is that the conversion factor can vary considerably from the equator to the poles. As per https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html#description, a conversion factor of 111120 can be used near the equator, but the option of reprojecting is better.